# Understanding about FUSE Server and camel

Tags: apache, jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse, jboss-esb

New to FUSE and Camel.

Downloaded CBR project from (https://github.com/jboss-fuse/quickstarts)  and was able to run it as standalone camel project.
cbr.xml  is as follows. This drops MSG  from a work/cbr/input directory into another. Could run this as mvn camel:run

```
 <route id="cbr-route">
            <from uri="file:work/cbr/input" />
            <log message="Receiving order ${file:name}" />
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <xpath>/order:order/order:customer/order:country = 'UK'</xpath>
                    <log message="Sending order ${file:name} to the UK" />
                    <to uri="file:work/cbr/output/uk" />
                </when>
                <when>
                    <xpath>/order:order/order:customer/order:country = 'US'</xpath>
                    <log message="Sending order ${file:name} to the US" />
                    <to uri="file:work/cbr/output/us" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <log message="Sending order ${file:name} to another country" />
                    <to uri="file:work/cbr/output/others" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
            <log message="Done processing ${file:name}" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

But ReadMe says start FUSE SEVER 
trying to understand why do i need FUSE container at all if i am able to run it as standlone

There is a project requirement that web service calls from Client go through FUSE for making it asynchronous.

assuming i would not need fuse container in this case

Thanks for taking the time and reading

Answer (score 1):

The FUSE is the container just like any other container , say tomcat, where you deploy your code to.

If you have a lot of integration scenarios and then you need to have a dedicated server to hold and run all your deploy-able. At least that is what I would suggest.

But if there are only a few of such scenarios you can use the power of camel , being  framework,use it as a supporting jar for your java code and run as a standalone code.

This means you are responsible to number of requests and issues regarding availability or scalability for that piece of integration code.